# Is it possible to see exactly what is being transferred over a wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking, monitoring

It came to me out of curiosity, "Could one monitor whatever is being transfered from modem/router to devices using the internet"?

So, I have a laptop at home and an iPad. Could I simply *see* what these devices *download* (i.e. surfing, videos, pictures, whatever..) from the internet? Im guessing this would be a problem regarding privacy? But, could it be set up for your own device or own home network or some other situation?

Comment: Of course, the first thing to do is to secure your net so that only authorized devices can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do it for educational purposes using applications like wireshark etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to access your router (usually 192.168.1.0; 192.168.1.1; or 192.168.0.1) as it is standard for routers to come with traffic logs.